# 8192 bytes when creating file

Tags: java, arrays

In my Java code I have function that gets file from the client in http request and converts that in to the file. I have this line there:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
```

what does 8192 bytes (8 kb) means here?

[This is one of the responses that I got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt/1111606#1111606), and want to make sure that I understand that code.

Comment: It means that you are creating a buffer to hold approximately 8.2 kb of data...

Comment: Please edit your question to reference the source of the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt/1111606#1111606

Comment: @Ed Swangren: 8.2?  Where did you get that?  Looks like 8.0 kb exactly.  1024 * 8.

Comment: Der, sorry, your right.  I am not making hard drives here :), dividing by 10 is wrong.  I was just saying that the point of the code in and of itself is very obvious.

Comment: I you're making hard drives, shouldn't that be 12 kb?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That it uses a buffer to read and write 8kB blocks at once. The number is fairly arbitary, but for performance reasons it makes sense to use a multiple of 512 bytes when writing a file, and preferably a multiple of the disks cluster size. 8kB is a reasonable buffer size for most purposes.

Answer (score 2):

This is the size of the array of bytes, meaning that your buffer will hold 8192 bytes at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, that is the amount of space you are using to read in the file. Without the rest of the code I can't tell if it is trying to read it all and cram it into 8k or if it is reading it in, 8k at a time, and then dumping it into the file.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt/1111606#1111606
This is where I have that number

Comment: Then it is reading in 8k at a time and sending that over to the file before grabbing the next 8k chunk. The justification is that 8k is a reasonable trade off between spinning your wheels calling functions, and wasting space when you get to the end of the file, because and it is reasonably close to the block size on many file systems.

Comment: How could we answer that when you show us no source code except for the array declaration/definition?

Answer (score 0):

8192 is maximum size of a package sending via network. 
char buffer[8192]; /* single packets are usually not bigger than 8192 bytes */
512 bytes is too small.

Comment: Can you provide some **references** about that claim: "`8192 is maximum size of a package sending via network`"?

Comment: That comment seems to have been copied from [*A brief programming tutorial in C for raw sockets*](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~steflik/cs455/rawip.txt), and misinterpreted as the "maximum size of a package[sic]," [which it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613734).