# Android max ping size less than 64K

Tags: android, networking, size, buffer, android-wifi

doing some tests with my ADP1 (version 1.6) I noticed that the maximum ping that I can send when it's connected with wifi (ad.hoc or with a router) is of 57740 bytes, shouldn't be 64K? I think it's related with the receiving buffer, do somebody know how to modify it or how to get information about it?

Answer (score 0):

This isnt the case with Android only. See this

[maximum packet size for a TCP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613734/maximum-packet-size-for-a-tcp-connection)