# AS3,AIR,Socket. How to check the progress of a writeObject() transfer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets, air

I'm dealing with AIR and Sockets, using a Server app and another as Client.

Server sends an object to Client:

```
clientSocket.writeObject(myObject);
```

Client has a listener, like this:

```
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketData);
```

How can I know the size of the incoming object? I need to monitoring this process, cause when the transfer is complete I need to do another processes.

I tried this, but doesn't work :

```
var total:int = 0;
private function socketData(e:ProgressEvent) :void {


if (total == 0) {
    total = socket.readInt();
}

if (socket.bytesAvailable >= total) {

    trace('COMPLETE');

    total = 0;

} else {

    trace('progress:' + socket.bytesAvailable + ' | total: ' + total);
}
```

}

This post does not work in my specific case: [AS3 / AIR readObject() from socket - How do you check all data has been received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345214/as3-air-readobject-from-socket-how-do-you-check-all-data-has-been-received)

Comment: after writing the object do you flush()?

Comment: Yes, I execute flush(), and the client receives the object correctly. My problem is that I can't control the progress of the transfer process.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it, with a hack:

SERVER: Send an object:

```
clientSocket.writeObject(image);// var image:Bitmap
clientSocket.flush();
```

CLIENT:

A. Have a listener to receive socket data:

`socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketData);`

B. Receive the bytes. When all the bytes are available, then read the object:

```
private var prevBytes:int = -1;

private var currentBytes:int = 0;

private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {

    if (currentBytes == prevBytes) {

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        currentBytes = 0;
        prevBytes = -1;

        var obj:* = socket.readObject();


    } else {

        prevBytes = currentBytes;

    }

    trace('Current : ' + currentBytes + ' | Prev : ' + prevBytes);

}

private function socketData(e:ProgressEvent):void {

    trace('on socketData : ' + currentBytes);

    if (currentBytes == 0) {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }

    currentBytes = socket.bytesAvailable;

}
```