# Optimal UDP packet size for audio and mobile networks

Tags: networking, udp, 3g, lte, 4g

I wish to encode audio with Opus encoder and send encoded frames in UDP packets.

There are ~1600 bytes per second.

As far as I read about UDP packet size 1400 bytes is good choice to start but most articles are about ethernet.

I can't find good references about 3G and 4G networks. I think I read somewhere that some mobiles networks compress packets.

Is it efficient to transmit audio in 500 bytes UDP packets vs 1400 bytes packets? May it triple mobile data usage?

Comment: I doubt you want to put a whole second's worth of data into a single packet. If you look a VoIP, it uses a lot of very small packets. That way, when packets are lost, and they will be, you only lose a very small amount of data. Losing one second's worth of audio will be quite noticeable.

Comment: It is reason why I consider smaller packets. I do not know how mobile networks transmit small UDP/IP packets. I could be wrong but I think I remember in GSM/GPRS there was some AT command/option to compress IP packets.

Comment: You might find this helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691158/udp-packet-size-latency-tradeoff-when-streaming-audio?rq=1