# WebRTC: datachannel drops messages?

Tags: html, webrtc

I am building a web application that uses webRTC datachannel. I sending data on mouse move to peer, but peer not receiving all the messages? why this? this is arising only when data sending fast.

using chrome 26.

How should I overcome from this?

Comment: This is a known problem, see [my own previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435121/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-webrtc-data-channel-messages) (where I first thought it was the size of each message but later found out it's just limited to 3kbps). By then there was no solution but if you find one I'd really like to know too.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late, but off the top of my head your problem is probably because datachannels use RTP (a UDP based protocol). UDP has no guarantee of delivery. This is perfect for real-time applications where packet loss is tolerable (multiplayer games, video streaming) because latency is much lower but it will lead to the kind of situation that you are facing.

If you can't use websockets to go through a server (TCP) and this really is a problem, maybe look into TCP over datachannels. I may have read somewhere that firefox supports TCP datachannels. I will edit this reply if I find any helpful information.

Comment: How do you force TCP ?