# Recommended filesize range for html/js/css/jpg/png for http transfer

Tags: javascript, html, http, optimization, file-transfer

When optimizing websites I've used concatenating and spriting to group related, reusable bits together but I'm often wondering how much or how little to package assets for delivery to the browser (sometimes automated tools aren't always part of my build process, though I prefer them).

I'm curious if there are some sensible guidelines just in the area of filesize when combining assets for delivery to the browser. Assuming no compression, or caching, just straightforward http transfer from a server to a browser with or without AJAX.

1. **What is the largest smallest filesize recommended?**

   I've heard that because of packet size (right? apologies if that was inept) that 1kb and 2kb of data will transfer at basically the same speed — is there a general threshold in kb where additional bytes start impacting transfer rate.
2. **Does transfer speed change linearly with filesize, or does it stair-stepper?**

   Extending the first question, does each kilobyte increase transfer speed in a fairly linear fashion? Or does it stair-stepper at packet-sized intervals (again, possibly inept word choice)?
3. **Is there a maximum size**

   Again, I know there are lot's contextual reasonings that influence this, but is there are filesize that is inadvisably large given current networks, browsers, or is it heavily dependent on the server and networks? If there is a good generalization, that's all I'm curious about.

It probably goes without saying, but I'm not a server/networking expert, just a front-end dev looking for some sensible defaults to guide quick decisions in asset optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the server, network, and client.

Use common sense, is the basic answer: Don't try to send several-megabyte bitmaps, or the page will take as long to load as if the person is trying to download any other several-megabyte file. A bunch of PNGs right there on a single page, on the other hand, will not really be noticeable to most modern users. In a more computational realm than you've asked, don't abuse iframes to redirect people to several steps of other web pages.

If you want more information about actual transmission, the maximum size of a single TCP packet is technically 64kB, but you're not really going to be sending more than 1.5kB in a single packet. However, TCP is stream-based, so the packet size is mostly irrelevant. You should be more concerned with bandwidth of modern machines, and considering how efficient we have video asset streaming nowadays, I really don't think you should be overly worried about delivering uncompressed assets to your users.

Because of the relative infrequency of actual delivery errors (which have to be corrected over TCP), along with the miniscule packet size relative to the size of most modern web pages, it's going to increase in delivery time pretty much linearly with total size (again, like one giant file). There are some details about multi-stage web page delivery that I'm leaving out, but they're mostly ignored when you're delivering high-asset-count web pages.

Edit: To address your concern (in the title) about transferring actual html/js files, they're just text in transfer. The browser does all of that rendering and code-running for you. If you have a single jpg, it's going to mostly overshadow *any* html/js you have on the page.

Transfer size: [maximum packet size for a TCP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613734/maximum-packet-size-for-a-tcp-connection)

http flow (a rough view): http://www.http.header.free.fr/http.html

Basically, as you get the primary html document representing the page as a whole (which is from your initial request to access the page), you parse for other URLs specified as images or scripts, and request those from the server for delivery to your session. The linked page is old but still relevant, and (I hope) easy to understand.

If you want actual bandwidth statistics for modern users, that's probably too much for me to track down. But if you want more technical info, wikipedia's pages on HTTP and TCP are pretty great.

Comment: Your answer is super helpful. If you could find secondary sources to support I'll gladly award the bounty sooner. Otherwise I'll wait to see if a better answer arrives.

Comment: Transfer size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613734/maximum-packet-size-for-a-tcp-connection ; http flow (a rough view): http://www.http.header.free.fr/http.html

Basically, as you get the primary html document representing the page as a whole (which is from your initial request to access the page), you parse for other URLs specified as images or scripts, and request those from the server for delivery to your session. The linked page is old but still relevant, and (I hope) easy to understand.

Comment: If you want actual bandwidth statistics for modern users, that's probably too much for me to track down. But if you want more technical info, wikipedia's pages on HTTP and TCP are pretty great.

Comment: Please place them in your answer, so that others may benefit.