# How does Python handle TCP responds you do not put in a variable?

Tags: python, memory, tcp, garbage

I'm working on a domotica program (Extron) and I have a memory issue. Therefor I was wondering what Python does with a TCP responds I do not put in a variable.

I have the following line of code:

```
Matrix.SendAndWait(str(States.MatrixStatus[States.RecorderStatus['Recorder 2']]['Fullscreen Input'])+'*'+\
                                           str(Collegerama['Recorder 2 Output'])+'%', 0.3, deliTag=b'\x0A')
```

the SendAndWait command is normally used to put the responds in a variable but I use it to slow down to program and to be sure the device is ready for a next command.

But not that I have a memory leak I wonder if the responds is put somewhere and is never cleared from the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Information is stored in the receive buffer as long as it does not overrun. Overrun is prevented by setting *TCP Receive Window size* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_tuning#Window_size ).  If packets have maximal size receive buffer is able to hold only one packet.

[maximum packet size for a TCP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613734/maximum-packet-size-for-a-tcp-connection)

So packets are initially stored in a receive buffer ( this is Network Layer in the OSI model ) From this receive buffer they are fetched by higher layers in the OSI model i.e. TCP ( Transport Layer in OSI model ) followed by removing headers to get the data / payload...

If the packets currently in the receive buffer are not fetched they are overwritten by newly incoming packets. So if speed of data processing is not fast enough information is lost,any newly incoming packet overwrites the old packet(s) in the receive buffer .

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

In https://www.cubrid.org/blog/understanding-tcp-ip-network-stack this is described in detail

> **Data Receiving**
>
> Now, let's take a look at how data is received. Data receiving is a
>   procedure for how the network stack handles a packet coming in. Figure
>   3 shows how the network stack handles a packet received.
>
> First, the NIC writes the packet onto its memory. It checks whether
>   the packet is valid by performing the CRC check and then sends the
>   packet to the memory buffer of the host. This buffer is a memory that
>   has already been requested by the driver to the kernel and allocated
>   for receiving packets. After the buffer has been allocated, the driver
>   tells the memory address and size to the NIC. When there is no host
>   memory buffer allocated by the driver even though the NIC receives a
>   packet, the NIC may drop the packet.
>
> After sending the packet to the host memory buffer, the NIC sends an
>   interrupt to the host OS.
>
> Then, the driver checks whether it can handle the new packet or not.
>   So far, the driver-NIC communication protocol defined by the
>   manufacturer is used.
>
> When the driver should send a packet to the upper layer, the packet
>   must be wrapped in a packet structure that the OS uses for the OS to
>   understand the packet. For example, sk_buff of Linux, mbuf of
>   BSD-series kernel, and NET_BUFFER_LIST of Microsoft Windows are the
>   packet structures of the corresponding OS. The driver sends the
>   wrapped packets to the upper layer.
>
> The Ethernet layer checks whether the packet is valid and then
>   de-multiplexes the upper protocol (network protocol). At this time, it
>   uses the ethertype value of the Ethernet header. The IPv4 ethertype
>   value is 0x0800. It removes the Ethernet header and then sends the
>   packet to the IP layer.
>
> The IP layer also checks whether the packet is valid. In other words,
>   it checks the IP header checksum. It logically determines whether it
>   should perform IP routing and make the local system handle the packet,
>   or send the packet to the other system. If the packet must be handled
>   by the local system, the IP layer de-multiplexes the upper protocol
>   (transport protocol) by referring to the proto value of the IP header.
>   The TCP proto value is 6. It removes the IP header and then sends the
>   packet to the TCP layer.
>
> Like the lower layer, the TCP layer checks whether the packet is
>   valid. It also checks the TCP checksum. As mentioned before, since the
>   current network stack uses the checksum offload, the TCP checksum is
>   computed by NIC, not by the kernel.
>
> Then it searches the TCP control block where the packet is connected.
>   At this time, `<source IP, source port, target IP, target port>` of the
>   packet is used as an identifier. After searching the connection, it
>   performs the protocol to handle the packet. If it has received new
>   data, it adds the data to the receive socket buffer. According to the
>   TCP state, it can send a new TCP packet (for example, an ACK packet).
>   Now TCP/IP receiving packet handling has completed.
>
> The size of the receive socket buffer is the TCP receive window. To a
>   certain point, the TCP throughput increases when the receive window is
>   large. In the past, the socket buffer size had been adjusted on the
>   application or the OS configuration. The latest network stack has a
>   function to adjust the receive socket buffer size, i.e., the receive
>   window, automatically.
>
> When the application calls the read system call, the area is changed
>   to the kernel area and the data in the socket buffer is copied to the
>   memory in the user area. The copied data is removed from the socket
>   buffer. And then the TCP is called. The TCP increases the receive
>   window because there is new space in the socket buffer. And it sends a
>   packet according to the protocol status. If no packet is transferred,
>   the system call is terminated.