# How to upload images to appengine from gwt

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, blobstore

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt) I am having similar problems to what that guy had in his. My upload server returns a redirect.

Specifically, I am not sure what FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent.getResults() returns. Sometimes, I get html of an img:

```
<img style="cursor: -moz-zoom-in;" 
    alt="http://<myapp>.appspot.com/servePic?blob-key=abcdef"
    src="http://<myapp>.appspot.com/servePic?blob-abcdef"
    height="1" width="1">
```

Sometimes I get the image data in bytes. Behavior varies on I dunno what. I get the first in development, and the second in production.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: It might help to share the code in question if you would like help debugging it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pretty good example of how to save/load/resize images with gwt & app engine.

http://code.google.com/p/swagswap/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/main/java/com/swagswap/dao%3Fstate%3Dclosed

Have a look in the dao implemenations and also the gwt interface packages.

Answer (score 0):

Does the project in this link still exists?

http://code.google.com/p/swagswap/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/main/java/com/swagswap/dao%3Fstate%3Dclosed

I tried to checked it out through eclipse but looks like it does not exist anymore.

Comment: Please use comments not answers for this type of conversation.