# How to retrieve inputStream from the server using fileUploader and GWT 2.4?

Tags: gwt, mvp, inputstream, gwt-2.4

I have a fileUploader widget that I'm using to select an xml file.  I then have a button that calls my handler in the viewImpl class when the user submits the selected file.  If I understand things correctly, from there I do a submit from the formPanel and the file is on the server.

```
@UiHandler("calculateComplexityButton")
    void onClickCalculateComplexity(ClickEvent e){
        formPanel.submit();
        //How do I get the inputStream back to here????
        presenter.getTask(inputStream);
    }
```

My problem is how do I get the inputStream off the server? I tried using an RPC call for all this, but when I try to get the inputStream I'm not pulling anything off the server.  I tried:

```
inputStream = request.getInputStream();
```

but it appears to be empty.  Any ideas on this?

I dropped the RPC code and used a simple HTTPRequest I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt). That gets me to the servlet, but the request doesn't have the file stream.  When I reach this line in the code:

```
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request); //Nothing is here in iter.
```

Comment: are you using Java on server side?

Comment: Yes.  I thought I had this figured out.  I'm using an RPC service call to a serviceImplServlet that extends RemoteServiceServlet.  I get to the servlet fine, but getting the inputStream that the fileUploader created and put on the server doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make an upload via RPC, thats why you have to submit your form to a servlet.

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
form.setAction("/upload");
```

So, when you do form.submit() it will send your file to the Action(Servlet). In the server side you can use the lib form apache ([commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)). You have many different way to get your file, you can save on disk, read on memory....

Comment: I'm not using RPC for the file upload, I'm using RPC to get to a RemoteServiceServlet implementation and from there I'm trying to get the file stream back.  I didn't set the form action though, so I have to use an HTTPServlet to pull the inputStream back off the server?

Comment: Okay, but I'm not seeing anything in the request.  Does the uploader widget set an attribute for the uploaded file?

Comment: You must set `fileUpload.setName("myFile")`. Then when you submit the form it will add the myFile attribute. Also your fileUpload must be in the form like `formPanel.add(fileUpload)`, but I think you know that. Are you using firebug to see the request?

Comment: That is what I was missing.  I'm using Firebug, but the Net panel wasn't enabled. Now the code is working!  Many thanks for the help!