# How to call a servlet from the viewImpl class in GWT?

Tags: gwt, servlets, mvp

I'm using GWT 2.4 with the MVP pattern, with uiBinder, and a widget: GwtUploader. When the user selects a file to upload and clicks a button, I need to make a call to a servlet.  I'm not calling a service, I just need to access the HttpRequest so I can pull the file that the widget has uploaded, but I'm not clear how to do this?

Here is the uiHandler code:

```
@UiHandler("loadFileButton")
    void onClickCalculate(ClickEvent e){
        String fileName = fileUploader.getFileName();

        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is you don't. In MVP, the View should defer that kind of behavior to the Presenter, which ideally would defer it to some server-side handler. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt) or [this article](http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/fileupload_with_gwt) for examples of how `FileUpload` can be used for this purpose. Since you mentioned you're using [GWTUpload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/), try reading the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted) article.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard look into the RequestBuilder class for calling arbitrary server urls on the same domain.

Comment: RequestBuilder is fine if you aren't using java servlets on the backend or if you don't want to use RPC.