# How to use the file uploaded using GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload

I'm preparing a project using Google Web Toolkit(GWT). I have to ask the user to upload a file(some text file) and have perform some operations on that file later. I have used FIleUpload to let the user upload a file, But what should I use to use that same file?

```
private FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
private FormPanel fp = new FormPanel();
```

Following is the code in onModuleLoad()

```
String filename = upload.getFilename();
if (filename.length() == 0)
     Window.alert("No file selected");
else {
    fp.submit();
    Window.alert("Please wait!!");
}
fp.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Window.alert(event.getResults());
}
});
```

I have searched regarding this. Some say that downloading from client side isn't possible or I may have to use HTML5 for the same. So what is preferred to be done when I want that file, uploaded by the user, as a text/string or a file for further use?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a servlet and map to form panel action. You'l receive file in your servlet. There you can store in specified path.

A good example and other choices here.

Have a look at :[Basic File upload in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt)

Later letting user to download it.

[Implementing a simple file download servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/implementing-a-simple-file-download-servlet/14281064#14281064)

Comment: I don't want the user to download any file as of now. The user will upload a file on the website which I have to use. So the user will upload and I have to download that file.

Comment: thank u for the link. But the first link doesn't have the complete code.

Comment: @user2327972 You mean the fileupload servlet ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't just get your file cause of what FileUpload() widget is. It is just a HTML `<input type='file'>` and behave the same: post data to form action url. So you should recive it in destination point with servlet. Somthing like [this](http://www.adrianwalker.org/2011/03/gwt-file-upload-with-event-based.html). And then you can process your file.