# GWT Open Windows Explorer / File Explorer on client side

Tags: java, gwt, windows-explorer

I'm trying to figure out if there's  away to load the O/S native file explorer given a location like \computer\mystuff .

I'm trying Window.open(), but that just seems to open a new tab.

I'm on GWT 2.6.1

Comment: That is completely impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers are prohibited from directly accessing the computer file system. It would have been a huge security hole otherwise.

You can ask a user to select file to upload or a location to save a file to, but you cannot select a specific location from your code - the default location is set by the browser's settings.

Comment: I wasn't looking to access files from the GWT client, but just a command to open up a file explorer to a location. But I guess that's not possible either.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt