# In GWT, is it possible to redirect a file upload to another REST service?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, file-upload, gwt

I've been reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845452/gwt-fileupload-with-servlet) about `FileUpload` in GWT. I have a GWT web app and a Spring Boot service with a `REST` API. The GWT app needs to allow the user to post a file, along with some `URL` query string parameters to the Spring Boot service.
Is it possible to redirect the upload so the file is sent directly to the Spring Boot service or do I need to upload it to a GWT `Servlet` first, then forward it on to the Spring Boot service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I figured it out. 
In the `FormPanel` you need to call `FormPanel.setAction()` and pass it the URL of the service you want to post to. 
The data will be posted once you call `FormPanel.submit()`.